# q-input has value then only Rules will apply

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

If q-input has value != '' then only i want to apply the Rules like required 8 number maximum. In the below code it gives me the required input error even it's null.

```
<q-input
    filled
    name="landline"
    label="Landline Phone Number"
    v-model="user.landline"
    placeholder="Landline Phone Number"
    ref="landlinePhoneNumber"
    type="number"
    :maxlength="8"
    :rules="[val => val!='' && val.length > 7 || 'Landline Required 8 digit']"
/>
```

Comment: try `lazy-rules="ondemand"` https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input

Comment: np:) I've added the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to add prop `lazy-rules`.
By default, it's set to 'ondemand', which means that validation will be triggered only when the component’s `validate()` method is manually called or when the wrapper QForm submits itself. [More info](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/input)

Comment: then you can accept the answer and upvote it ;)

Comment: Not capable of a vote now. Don't worry once I reach up to level I will upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to return true when the field is `null` first, then validate only if it's not null. Also, add the prop `lazy-rules` so that it only validates when the form field loses focus.

Here is how I did it in Vue 3, using composable and TypeScript. The form field component:

```
<q-input
        class="q-mt-md"
        filled
        v-model="id_number"
        label="ID Number "
        type="text"
        hint="Optional/Leave blank if not available"
        lazy-rules
        :rules="[(val) => isNumberBlankOrValid(val) || 'Invalid ID Number']"
      />
```

The method `isNumberBlankOrValid` called from the field above:

```
    const isNumberBlankOrValid = (val: string) => {
    if (val.length === 0) {
      return true
    }
    return isValidNumber(val)
  }
```

The `isValidNumber` for other fields that must be filled:

```
const isValidNumber = (val: string) => val && isNumeric(val)
```

The `isNumeric` method is a simple regex for validating numbers:

```
const isNumeric =  (value: string) => {
  return /^\d+$/.test(value)
}
```